# How can I show the same matplotlib figure multiple times in IPython shell?

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter

I ran the following code to plot a single line with matplotlib object-oriented API.

```
$ ipython --pylab
In [1]: fig = plt.figure() # An empty figure is shown in popped up window here
In [2]: ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
In [3]: ax.plot(arange(10)) # no figure is shown up here
Out[3]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x7fb134118400>]
In [4]: fig.show()
```

When `fig = plt.figure()` is executed, new window is popped up and it shows an empty figure. After plotting by `ax.plot(arange(10))`, no figure is shown automatically, so I tried to show the figure by `fig.show()` and I got this error.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-6ebedab27258> in <module>()
----> 1 fig.show()

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py in show(self, warn)
    409         if manager is not None:
    410             try:
--> 411                 manager.show()
    412                 return
    413             except NonGuiException:

~/.pyenv/versions/3.6.4/envs/analysis/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py in show(self)
    560             self.canvas.draw_idle()
    561         # Raise the new window.
--> 562         self.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 1)
    563         self.canvas.manager.window.attributes('-topmost', 0)
    564         self._shown = True

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attributes'
```

But an ugly one-liner like this correctly shows a line chart.

```
plt.figure().add_subplot(1,1,1).plot(arange(10))
```

It seems like IPython shell cannot show the same figure multiple times. How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: If you are in interactive mode (which it sounds like you are) then you shouldn't need to call `show()`. `ax.plot()` should update the figure

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I also expected `ax.plot()` showed the updated figure, but it didn't. Updated the question to clarify this point.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how I treated the windows with the empty figure. I always closed it right after executing `fig = plt.figure()`. I should not do this. Keeping it opened allows `ax.plot()` to draw the line on the opened figure.